# Can not see mounts after using mount -a in Debian 10

Tags: debian, nfs, file-server

I am trying to create some mount points between two Debian 10 machines using NFS. On the server I have this information in my /etc/exports file:

```
/home 10.13.38.184(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/var/nfs 10.13.38.184(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Then on my client I have this in the /etc/fstab file:

```
10.13.38.84:/home /mnt/nfs/home nfs4 defaults,user,exec,noauto 0 0
10.13.38.84:/var/nfs /mnt/nfs/var/nfs nfs4 defaults,user,exec,noauto 0 0
```

Both files have been saved. I have made sure that the firewall allows nfs. After typing the

```
mount -a
```

command. It runs as if it was successful, but I do not see the mounts. I use "mount" or "df -h" to look for the mounts and there is nothing on the mounts I created. Not sure what else I am missing. Suggestions? Please

Answer (score 1):

The ***noauto*** parameter you specified for your two filesystems instructs mount -a to ignore them!

Quoted from man mount :

> mount -a [-t type] [-O liste_options]
>
> (usually  given in a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in
> fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper
> options)  to be mounted as indicated, **except for those whose line
> contains the noauto keyword.**

Comment: That is where one of the issues lies. When I take off the noauto or try to mount them directly, the client will hang up and I recieve a connection timed out error.